# MongoDB/Node Lookup/match

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Currently I have 3 Schemas:

**UserFavorite** (This schema is supposed to be used  to store the favorites the user has decided)

```
var UserFavoriteSchema = new Schema({
    _id: {
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        auto: true
    },
    favoriteId: {
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        required: true
    },
    userId: {
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        required: true
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('UserFavorite', UserFavoriteSchema);
```

**Favorites** (This schema holds the available favorites in the system)

```
var FavoriteSchema = new Schema({
    _id: {
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        auto: true
    },
    storeId: {
        type: String,
        auto: true
    },
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    ...
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Favorite', FavoriteSchema);
```

**User Schema**

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
    _id: {
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        auto: true
    },
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    ...
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

---

Everytime an user favorites an item (from Favorite collection) I will store the ID on UserFavorite.

**My problem:**
I'm trying to retrieve all favorite data from a given user (all infos from Favorite that are presented on UserFavorite).

Here's my code:

```
    UserFavorite.aggregate([
                {
                    $match: {
                        "userId": mongoose.Types.ObjectId(userId)
                    }
                },
                {
                    $lookup: {
                        "from": "favorites",
                        "localField": "favoriteId",
                        "foreignField": "_id",
                        "as": "favorites"
                    }
                }
            ]).exec(function (err, data) {
                if(err){
                    //ERROR
                }else{
//Everything's okay

}

});
```

**My expected result:**

I expect to have each User favorite inside of Favorites array. (the 'as' from Lookup), like the following:

```
[
    {
        "userId": "5bc74f4ac42a2719b8827404",
        "favorites": [
            {
                "_id": "5bc7d92f4235972ea805664e",
                "thumbnail": "string",
                "storeId": "string",
                "name": "string",
            },
            {
                "_id": "5bc7d9414235972ea805664f",
                "thumbnail": "no_image",
                "storeId": "1234",
                "name": "Fulério Store",
            }
        ]
    },
]
```

But what I get is:

```
[
    {
        "userId": "5bc74f4ac42a2719b8827404",
        "favoriteId": "5bc7d92f4235972ea805664e",
        "favorites": [
            {
                "_id": "5bc7d92f4235972ea805664e",
                "thumbnail": "string",
                "storeId": "string",
                "name": "string",
                "__v": 0
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "userId": "5bc74f4ac42a2719b8827404",
        "favoriteId": "5bc7d9414235972ea805664f",
        "favorites": [
            {
                "_id": "5bc7d9414235972ea805664f",
                "thumbnail": "no_image",
                "storeId": "1234",
                "name": "Fulério Store",
                "__v": 0
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

It brings the informations of each favorite of "UserFavorite", instead of putting all favorites from a given user into an array.

How could I get it working?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What is the `auto` role in the schema define? also, can you please try to alter `Schema.ObjectId` to `type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Favorite'` and try again?

Comment: You should start aggregation from `User` schema instead of `UserFavorites` OR you can use `$group` with `userId`here.

Comment: Hello guys, thank you very much! @OmerShukar, the auto option comes from here https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/1285#issuecomment-13419165
changing these options didn't change the result.

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet can you please help me to understand how could I do this with 3 collections? (User, UserFavorite, Favorite)? i'm sorry for my simple questions, this is my first adventure on noSql waters.

Comment: Could you post the sample collection from all the collections

Comment: Hello mr. @AnthonyWinzlet, I've added the User schema. Thank you very much!

Comment: What version of mongodb you are using?

Comment: Hello @AnthonyWinzlet, I'm using v4.0.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to use the $group operator, what you've got now is akin to

1. Find every UserFavorite for the user_id (there are 2 items returned)
2. For each of those items, lookup that favorite

Try adding this as the last stage of the aggregation

```
{
    $group: {
         _id: "$userId",
         favoriteArray: {$addToSet: "$favorites"}
    }
}
```

The $group stage will roll them all up based on the userId

Comment: How could I rename, for example, the `_id` field from inside the "$favorites"? I managed to rename the `_id` field using $project, from the user Id field, but not the field inside of the returned $favorites

Comment: You should be able to add a `$project` stage before the group to rename it

`{ $project: {'favorites.favoriteId': '$favorites._id' } }`

FYI - this will only work if there is 1 item in the array, if there are multiple then it will add every _id to that field. In which case you would need to `$unwind` the array and then rename, but it's probably more effort than it's worth

Comment: I got it! Thank you very much Robert!